# How to authenticate an iOS app in swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, active-directory, restful-authentication

I was wondering how to authenticate api calls in swift to a custom service I made that authenticates users with active directory.  Currently my application stores an integer value, I want to post that to the service.

```
let thing = Int(emailTextField.text!) 
// POST method goes here ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just **authenticate** my app with this piece of code.

```
if(isValidEmail && isValidPassword){
        print("sending to server for verification")
        let params = ["user" : ["email" : "\(email!)", "password" : "\(password!)"]]
        let url: String = "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in"
        Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: params, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil).validate().responseJSON{
            response in
            switch response.result{
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value{
                    let jsn = JSON(value)
                    print("jsn: \(jsn)")
                    let authentication_token = jsn["authentication_token"]
                    if(authentication_token != nil){
                        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dasboardViewController") as! DashBoardController
                        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                break
            case .Failure:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure `Alamofire` is imported. I have rails server in the backend and this was tested in localhost. Also, Authentication is done using email and password instead of numbers, And it returns a json containing `authentication_token` field.